# how can I get a ref to Tree?

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I don't manage to get a react ref to the tree , how can I do this ?

```
<Tree ref={treeRef} value={nodes} selectionMode="single" selectionKeys={null} onSelectionChange={onNodeSelect} />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const treeRef = useRef<Tree>();

<Tree
        ref={(arg) => {
          if (arg) treeRef.current = arg;
        }}
/>
```